# Steam doesn't launch because it needs additional packages

Tags: package-management, software-installation, steam

I installed Steam using Ubuntu Software Center, but when I tried to launch it, it says it needs additional packages.

The error in the terminal:

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
    libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-quantal:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal:i386
sudo: unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted
sudo: setresuid() [0, 0, 0] -> [115, -1, -1]: Operation not permitted

sudo: unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted
sudo: setresuid() [0, 0, 0] -> [115, -1, -1]: Operation not permitted
Press return to continue:
```

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: @mickmackusa please don't add quote formatting to output in a terminal - it's perfectly clear what it is imho. Most code blocks in questions here are output from commands and code + quote is a pain to format. Errors seen elsewhere than a terminal/tty can be quote formatted instead of code formatted to distinguish from other text.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about getting Steam working, but since it's saying it needs packages that you don't have installed, try installing them:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-quantal libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal
```

If you're not comfortable running that command in a terminal, open the software center, look for these two packages, and install them:

```
libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-quantal
libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest this.  I use Steam and have not had this error show up but it looks like some of the files for `mesa` are missing....without them Steam will not run.  I think this will fix the OP's issue.. +1

Comment: I DID have this error, I was able to get around it by explicitly installing those packages.

Comment: When I try to run the command, Terminal gives an error
`guest-0PJgJU@Raul-Laptop:~$ sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-quantal libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal
sudo: unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted
sudo: setresuid() [0, 0, 0] -> [115, -1, -1]: Operation not permitted
guest-0PJgJU@Raul-Laptop:~$ 
`

Comment: @Raul are you logging in as a guest? If so, try first logging in as your normal user, the one you made during the install.

Comment: @djeikyb Actually I have only one account on my PC, and I really don't understand why it thinks I am a guest.

Comment: @Raul What version of Ubuntu are you using? It looks like your user doesn't have admin rights. Do you remember setting a password for root (or super user, or administrator, ..)?